# Kafka Streams: How to avoid forwarding downstream twice when repartitioning

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In my application I have KafkaStreams instances with a very simple topology: there is one processor, with a key-value store, and each incoming message gets written to the store and is then forwarded downstream to a sink.

I would like to increase the number of partitions I have for my source topic, and then reprocess the data, so that each store will contain only keys relevant to its partition. (I understand this is done using the Application Reset Tool). However, while reprocessing the data, I don't want to forward anything downstream; I want only new data to be forwarded. (Otherwise, consumers of the result topic will handle old values again). My question: is there an easy way to achieve this? Any build-in mechanism that can assist me in telling reprocessed data and new data apart maybe?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not build-in mechanism. But you might be able to just remove the sink operation that is writing to the result topic when you reprocess your data -- when reprocessing is done, you stop the application, add the sink again and restart. Not sure if this works for you.

Another possible solution might be, to use a `transform()` an implement an offset-based filter. For each input topic partitions, you get the offset of the first new message (this is something you need to do manually before you write the `Transformer`). You use this information, to implement a filter as a custom `Transformer`: for each input record, you check the record's partition and offset and drop it, if the record's offset is smaller then the offset of the first new message of this partition.